# Java Project versions in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control

When I program I often end up making 5 or 6 different versions so that way if I mess up I can return back to an older version.

In the Eclipse IDE, is there a way I can just click "create new version" or something so I don't have to make an entirely new project and copy and paste the previous source code to the new version I just made?

Is there any version manager for Eclipse? If so where can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control_system), such as [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/), [Git](http://git-scm.com/), or [CVS](http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/)? They are designed for versioning projects without needing to make copies of them. And to be honest, they do a much better job than any individual can (when used properly) at tracking what changes were made and when.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a preference between "Subversive" and "Subclipse"?

Are they both equally good?

Comment: I personally prefer Subclipse. But I know people who prefer Subversive.

Answer (score 0):

Something that can be a little quicker to set-up, but potentially less robust to long term use, is to use a service like Dropbox, and set a Dropbox directory as your workspace (provided you aren't working on sensitive code, with personal information, assorted caveats to apply to any cloud-style service).

Dropbox does have revert options.  Of course, in Eclipse you can also copy and paste whole projects.

Long-term, if you have heavy version control/group work needs, I totally agree with Thomas's solution.  But, as a quick and dirty, something like Dropbox works quite well.